# How can I make my background image resize by width but not height?

Tags: html, css, image

Right now I'm using this code to resize my background image:

```
background: url(../website/assets/shadedbackground.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

It looks and works great when the browser window's width is resized (the image is cropped at it's sides and made slightly smaller), but when the height is resized the entire image is shrunk down, which messes everything up. What I want to do is make the height permanent but still let the width resize as this code does currently.

I hope that makes sense. I'm still pretty new at this. Thanks!

Comment: could you make a little [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show a little bit more about the context ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using break points with media queries?

The use of cover makes the image scale. That's its purpose. If browser resize alters things then you have to modify your code.

For more information see:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

If you post an example either at jsfiddle or elsewhere people will be able to give a more detailed answer.